# Spring Web-Flux: How to return a Flux to a web client on request?

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

We are working with spring boot 2.0.0.BUILD_SNAPSHOT and spring boot webflux 5.0.0 and currently we cant transfer a flux to a client on request.

Currently I am creating the flux from an iterator:

```
public Flux<ItemIgnite> getAllFlux() {
    Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, ItemIgnite>> iterator = this.getAllIterator();

    return Flux.create(flux -> {
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            flux.next(iterator.next().getValue());
        }
    });
}
```

And on request I am simply doing:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/all", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public Flux<ItemIgnite> getAllFlux() {
    return this.provider.getAllFlux();
}
```

When I now locally call `localhost:8080/all` after 10 seconds I get a `503` status code. Also as at client when I request `/all` using the `WebClient`:

```
public Flux<ItemIgnite> getAllPoducts(){
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");

    Flux<ItemIgnite> f = webClient.get().uri("/all").accept(MediaType.ALL).exchange().flatMapMany(cr -> cr.bodyToFlux(ItemIgnite.class));
    f.subscribe(System.out::println);
    return f;

}
```

Nothing happens. No data is transferred.

When I do the following instead:

```
public Flux<List<ItemIgnite>> getAllFluxMono() {
    return Flux.just(this.getAllList());
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/allMono", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public Flux<List<ItemIgnite>> getAllFluxMono() {
    return this.provider.getAllFluxMono();
}
```

It is working. I guess its because all data is already finished loading and just transferred to the client as it usually would transfer data without using a flux.

What do I have to change to get the flux streaming the data to the web client which requests those data?

**EDIT**

I have data inside an [ignite cache](https://ignite.apache.org/features/sql.html). So my `getAllIterator` is loading the data from the ignite cache:

```
public Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, ItemIgnite>> getAllIterator() {
    return this.igniteCache.iterator();
}
```

**EDIT**

adding `flux.complete()` like @Simon Baslé suggested:

```
public Flux<ItemIgnite> getAllFlux() {
    Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, ItemIgnite>> iterator = this.getAllIterator();

    return Flux.create(flux -> {
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            flux.next(iterator.next().getValue());
        }

        flux.complete(); // see here
    });
}
```

Solves the `503` problem in the browser. But it does not solve the problem with the `WebClient`. There is still no data transferred.

**EDIT 3**

using `publishOn` with `Schedulers.parallel()`:

```
public Flux<ItemIgnite> getAllFlux() {
    Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, ItemIgnite>> iterator = this.getAllIterator();

    return Flux.<ItemIgnite>create(flux -> {
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            flux.next(iterator.next().getValue());
        }

        flux.complete();
    }).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
}
```

Does not change the result.

Here I post you what the WebClient receives:

```
value :[Item ID: null, Product Name: null, Product Group: null]
complete
```

So it seems like he is getting One item (out of over 35.000) and the values are null and he is finishing after.

Comment: Could you explain what `getAllIterator` is doing? Is it blocking? Reading data from a database? From memory?

Answer (score 4):

One thing that jumps out is that you never call `flux.complete()` in your `create`.

But there's actually a factory operator that is tailored to transform an `Iterable` to a `Flux`, so you could just do `Flux.fromIterable(this)`

Edit: in case your `Iterator` is hiding complexity like a DB request (or any blocking I/O), **be advised this spells trouble**: anything blocking in a reactive chain, if not isolated on a dedicated execution context using `publishOn`, has the potential to block not only the entire chain but other reactive processes has well (as threads can and will be used by multiple reactive processes).

Neither `create` nor `fromIterable` do anything in particular to protect from blocking sources. I think you are facing that kind of issue, judging from the hang you get with the `WebClient`.

Comment: adding `flux.complete()` makes it possible to ge the expected result when I test it in my browser. I dont get a `503` anymore. It does not solve the problem when I try it with `WebClient` there are still no results.

Comment: I see two other issues; your `getAllIterator` is blocking, so you need to schedule that on a specific Scheduler (see reactor docs on `publishOn`). On the WebClient side, you're calling `subscribe` on the `Flux` but also returning it - you should not do both.

Comment: I edited my post to show you how I added the `publishOn` and to provide the result arriving at my `WebClient` p. s. the subscribe on the flux is just to check if there is output arriving.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my Object `ItemIgnite` which I transfer. The system Flux seems not to be able to handle this. Because If I change my original code to the following:

```
public Flux<String> getAllFlux() {
    Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, ItemIgnite>> iterator = this.getAllIterator();

    return Flux.create(flux -> {
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            flux.next(iterator.next().getValue().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is working fine. Without `publishOn` and without `flux.complete()`. Maybe someone has an idea why this is working.